# C printf not working on ubuntu 13.10 terminal

Tags: 13.04, command-line, gcc, c

I'm new in ubuntu so please bear with me.

I need to create a C based program for a course in my university. I was using **openSUSE** as the OS and **konsole** as the terminal emulator when I was in the university's lab.

So basically I need to install openSUSE on my system or use a VM to do so. But i feel lazy to do that, so I tried to run it on my Ubuntu instead of openSUSE.

However, no C code seems working on Ubuntu's terminal. The compiling is success, but its not running, or at least the `printf` is not running.

This is my code, a very very simple one :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("test");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with `gcc test.c -o test` everything works fine and i get an executable file.

Then I try to run it by `./test`, but the `printf` is not printed. No error or warning was shown.

Am I missing something?

Note : my `gcc` is the new one, it should has no problem.

Comment: Can you do a `pwd` on the location where your `test.c` file is located and edit your question with the output?

Comment: when running `./test` please copy and paste the terminal content here

Comment: I can see the output of the program correctly you did here. But the the one thing i noticed is that there is no `\n` so the text `test` is mixed with the line `user@user-pc:$`

Comment: @cshubhamrao : yes that's what i'm trying to check

Comment: @HakeemWahab already checked it on my system :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the output, of your program:
[image]

The text from `printf ("test");` is printed and you can see it before the line `shubham@shubham-pc:~$`

Since there is no `\n` in your program, a newline is not printed at end and hence the default line of console gets printed after it

To solve this your program should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s \n","test");
    return 0;
}
```

The thing I've done here is that, I used a format string (`%s`) to print `test` and added a newline (`\n`) after it.

Here is the output after the edits:

[image]

Comment: Yess, its there, i dont see it. Thanks a lot for your help :D

Comment: My issue was that I had the wrong slash direction in my newline `/` vs \.